# TYPO3 Repository findByUid (magic method) stops commandController script and returns blank page

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I update records with a CommandController. When I do a findByUid() in the command then only a blank white page returns and the script ends.
Its running with **TYPO3 7.6.35 ELTS**

I do a

```
DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->xyzRepository->findByUid(123));
die('died');
```

The Debug-Output does **not** appear, the die does **no** output and instead there is only a blank white page.

I added the function  manually to the Repo:

```
public function findByUid($uid) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->equals('uid', $uid)
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

After this - it works fine. My Debug-Output is a QueryResult with my record and the die() says "died" as expected.

I have no idea why this happens. There are multiple repos in use inside the command and if I dont have to, I dont want to create the findByUid in every repo by myself. Anyone any idea to solve/fix this?

Comment: first:  
white page is an error page with all output supressed. try to switch to develop mode in the install tool, so you can see the output in the FE. Otherwise you need to inspect your server log.

Comment: The debug mode is enabled. and the server logs seems not to be accessible in Mittwald packages

Comment: The CommandController is a script to use via Scheduler Task or via CLI, but not in the FE of the website. Where are you executing this CommandController and in which context?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler with the Scheduler. It is not in FE. The error in FE I Force to See via f:debug and die()

Comment: What about calling it via CLI? Would make more sense and you get the debug directly.

Comment: That is not really an options because there are many installations configured with this command. It would be a lot of work to change this for all pages. 
The weird thing is, it has worked for the last monthes/years without problems (at least never came a negative feedback and in the tests it works too)